# ¿Fue alguna vez "besos" sinónimo de "labios"?

Tags: historia, sinónimos

Leo en la ortografía de Nebrija:

> DIFINICION QUARTA
>   *Que la Muda es Letra que ſe forma en tal parte de la boca que ni poco ni mucho puede ſonar por eſtàr cerrados los lugares por donde avìa de ſalir aquella boz* : **como la B, i la P, que no pueden por sì ſonar por eſtàr los bezos apretados** : la T, i la D, por eſtàr la lengua atraveſada entre las (helgaduras) de los dientes : la C, i la G, por eſtàr la Campanilla (traveſada) en el (gargavero).

La negrita es mía. Entiendo que se refiere a que para pronunciar la B y la P hay que juntar, o apretar, los labios; pero me ha parecido gracioso que use la palabra "besos" para explicarlo.
Actualmente el DLE no recoge ninguna acepción de "beso" como "labio":

> [**beso**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5PQqqPX)
>   Del lat. *basium*, voz de or. celta.
>
> 1. m. Acción y efecto de besar.
> 2. m. Ademán simbólico de besar.
> 3. m. coloq. Golpe que se dan las cosas cuando se tropiezan unas con otras.
> 4. m. coloq. Golpe violento que mutuamente se dan dos personas en la cara o en la cabeza.

Pero ambas palabras están relacionadas de una manera muy obvia, aunque sea a nivel semántico.
Mi pregunta es: ¿eran sinónimas estas palabras antes?

Comment: Curioso que el propio Nebrija en su diccionario español-latino distinguiera entre "beso honesto" (_osculum_) y "beso de enamorado" (_basium_). Curioso también que hoy día la palabra que usemos mayormente sea la versión enamorada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Es que *[bezo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5RBHPkG)* significa "labio"! El DLE dice que es "de origen incierto". Es la primera vez en mi vida que leo tal cosa pero parece que la palabra ha tenido cierto uso.

[image]

En el CORDE curiosamente aparece unas cuantas veces *bezo*. Hay una obra de un tal Gonzalo Correas, de 1627, donde hay toda una serie de dichos donde se lo utiliza. En una línea específicamente dice "No por el beso, sino por el bezo", como para despejar la duda de si se trata de un error, y más abajo:

> "Bezo" es "la kostunbre", i tómase en mala parte, "mal bezo": mala
>   kostunbre, o mal enseñamiento; de akí "abezar" es enseñar, i todo naze
>   del ABC, por donde se komienza a deprender. Tanbién "bezo" es el labio
>   grueso, i se pudo dezir de akí "abezar".

En otros documentos queda claro que *bezo* es efectivamente un labio, o la zona que rodea a los labios:

> y el cabello largo, e la barba luenga, en la cual solamente tenía en
>   la punta de la barba y en el bezo muy pocos pelos e blancos

Y aquí tenemos un bezo con linaje:

> cuando se imita alguna boca que este riendo, que entonces para bien
>   imitar la risa, convendríale abrir un poco de la boca y alzarla de los
>   cantos y cerrar otro tanto de los ojos cuanto se abre de ella; mas hay
>   ciertas genealogías de Príncipes y Reyes, como son el Rey Nuestro
>   Señor y lo fué el Emperador Don Carlos y sus descendientes, los cuales
>   tienen el bezo de abajo un poco descuidado y relevado hacia fuera, lo
>   cual denota majestad, y aunque en alguna manera parece abrirse la boca
>   no por eso descubre los dientes sinó quedan desemulados.

Answer (score 2):

En el [diccionario de autoridades](http://web.frl.es/DA.html) se encuentra lo siguiente:

> [BEZO](http://web.frl.es/dtSearch/dtisapi6.dll?cmd=getdoc&DocId=44445&Index=C%3a%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CDA_INDEX&HitCount=1&hits=1+&SearchForm=%2fDA_form.html) s. m. El lábio gruesso, y que sale mucho hácia fuera, como de ordinário le tienen los Negros. Covarr. dice que de *Bucca* se dixo Buza, y de aqui Bezo. Lat. *Labium*. COVARR. en esta palab. Los que escriben de Phisonomía dicen que los que tienen los lábios gruessos, que llamamos *bezos*, son escarnecedores y maldicientes. QUEV. Mus. 6. Rom. 59.

Así que al menos acá si se hace una referencia, así sea a labios *gruesos*.

Tambien se encuentra allí una segunda entrada:

> [BEZO](http://web.frl.es/dtSearch/dtisapi6.dll?cmd=getdoc&DocId=44446&Index=C%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CDA_INDEX&HitCount=1&hits=1%20&SearchForm=%2FDA_form.html). Se llama tambien el costurón ò carne levantada al rededor de la herída quando está enconada, que por ser à semejanza del labio gruesso se dice assi: y tambien se llama Lábio. Lat. *Tumidum os vulneris*.